# Question about double integrals

Tags: integration

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong on this problem. I've been stuck on this problem for a while. Please help.

> Sketch the region $D$ that gives rise to repeated integral and change the order of integration.
>
> [image]

Below is my work. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have the suggestions given clarified your doubts? If not, try also to plot the region reversing the axes.

Comment: And, as further suggestion, draw the picture bigger!

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You have to divide the reverse integral in two pieces, notably

$$\int_{\frac12}^1 \int_{x^3}^{x} f(x,y)dydx=\int_{\frac18}^{\frac12} \int_{\frac12}^{\sqrt[3]y} f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{\frac12}^1 \int_{y}^{\sqrt[3]y} f(x,y)dxdy$$

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why it needs to be divided into two pieces. Whats your logic behind that?

Comment: because for y between 1/8 and 1/2 the lower limit for x is 1/2 while for y between 1/2 and 1 the lower limit for x is y

Comment: @Hritik I've added the sketch also for the reverse integral

Answer (score 1):

The inner limit is always on the right should be $\sqrt[3]{y}$

However, the left limit is not always $x=y$, it is bounded on the left by $\max(\frac12, {y}).$

Comment: oops, i got it opposite. thanks